# Python(Flask)-Method Not Allowed The method is not allowed for the requested URL

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am new to flask, i just picked it up for a school project, basically i did some calculations in python and am supposed to link it whit a react front end. whenever i run the Python(Flask) code and paste the url http://127.0.0.1:5173/api/calculate_feed i get a 405 error
Here is the python code

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
from ListGenration import get_feedstuff_for_hardcoded_animal

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes

@app.route('/api/calculate_feed', methods=['POST'])
def calculate_feed():
    data = request.get_json()

    # Check if 'animal_type' is provided in the request
    if 'animal_type' not in data or 'purpose' not in data:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid request. Missing animal_type or purpose.'}), 400

    animal_type = str(data['animal_type'])
    stage = str(data['purpose'])

    # Get the suitable feedstuff for the chosen animal type
    feedstuff_info = get_feedstuff_for_hardcoded_animal(animal_type, stage)

    if feedstuff_info:
        # Prepare the response
        response = {
            "totalProtein": feedstuff_info.get('Estimated_Protein', 0),
            "totalEnergy": feedstuff_info.get('Estimated_Energy', 0),
            "totalFiber": feedstuff_info.get('Estimated_Fiber', 0)
        }

        return jsonify(response), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': f'No feedstuff information available for {animal_type} in {stage} stage.'}), 404

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5173)
```

and here is the react code(the part that makes a request and takes the response)Note: i did not write this code the front end developer did and am don't know react

```
 const handleAnimalClick = (item) => {
    // Use Axios for API request
    setActions({ ...actions, purpose: item })
    axios.post('/api/calculate_feed', { animal_type: selectedAnimal, purpose:item })
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.data;
        console.log('Nutritional Information:', data);

        // Update the state with the received nutritional information
        setTotalProtein(data.totalProtein || 'Daily');
        setTotalEnergy(data.totalEnergy || 'Daily');
        setTotalFiber(data.totalFiber || 'Daily');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching nutritional information:', error);
      });
     
   
  };
```

I don't know what a doing wrong, i am running the flack in a Virtual Environment
(venv) ...\GDSC_Project\Python_Files python server.py

- Serving Flask app 'server'
- Debug mode: on
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5173
  Press CTRL+C to quit
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 125-115-080

and am running the react code simultaneously
VITE v5.0.12  ready in 458 ms

➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
➜  Network: use --host to expose
➜  press h + enter to show help

What i tried

- CHANGING the flask port to match that of react host
- Running the flask in a virtual environment
- Enabled CORS for all routs

Comment: Show us the flask log line from the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you might be misunderstanding a few basics. Some important fundamentals:

- When you run Flask, you are running a web server that will answer TCP requests on the port you indicate.  If you want to interact with your **flask** app, you need to be sure the request goes to 127.0.0.1:5173 (or whatever your port is).
- When you enter an address in your browser and hit enter, you are performing a GET. If you are trying to access that API endpoint directly in your browser, you will have a method problem because your route explicitly states it is limited to "POST"
- When you run the development server for **react**, you are running a different web server on a different TCP port. If you expect to be accessing react-generated content, you probably want to see `127.0.0.1:12345` (or whatever your *react* port is) in your browser address bar.  You *cannot* run multiple servers on the same port number
- When you make requests from JS, using a relative URL like you do here: `axios.post('/api/calculate_feed',`, the browser assumes you want to talk to the *same server* as the one hosting the page.  In other words, you may want to try being explicit about the server, ie try `axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5173/api/calculate_feed',` and use that to better understand what your problem is.

In summary, your browser is probably not talking to the server process you think you are talking to AND/OR you are inadvertently using an HTTP method that is not defined (you need to define a route to cover GET).

Check these details carefully and see if that leads to your solution.

Comment: Ok i will try the and see if they work, thanks

Comment: Thank you really much  for the help full advice Mr Bill Huneke,  it works now